# Will USB-PD work with and extension cable in the circuit?

Tags: charger, automotive, 12v, cellphone, usb-pd

I want to replace the USB type A port on my trucks dash with a USB-C panel mount and give it the ability to "fast charge" my phone. Unless there is a product that I am overlooking it seems I would need to install a PCB charger [this](https://www.datapro.net/products/usb-c-panel-mount-extension-cable.html) and than plug in something like [this](https://www.datapro.net/products/usb-c-panel-mount-extension-cable.html) panel mount which is essentially a 1' Male to female. Should it work if I have charger > extension cable > phone cable > phone? Or should I strip the male end of the extension cable, desolder the chargers female port, solder extension cable to charger?

Comment: An USB C extension cable is not defined by the specification, USB C also defined a max voltage drop over the cable. Because a extension cable has resistance, it is very likely to violate the spec when used in combination with a spec following cable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are proposing as the links seem broken.  To get a USB-C charger port in your dash get a panel mounted charger, install it in your dash, and run a 12 volt supply from the fuse box.

Here's one example of such a charger:
https://powerwerx.com/panel-usbc-pd-power-delivery-qc30-blue

Any extension cable would violate the USB-C spec, as @Ferrybig points out.  If you are chopping of the ends of USB cables and soldering things to the broken remains then you are likely doing it wrong.  USB is very sensitive to resistance and a soldering cables will mess with the carefully calculated wire resistance in the cable, which can make the negotiation of voltage and current impossible, potentially damaging the device being charged.

An automotive USB-C charger will be built to handle the variable voltage from a car battery and the random length of the wires to the charger, so let that be where any issues of wire length be addressed.  The device being charged should not have any extension cable to the charger, only a cable that meets the USB-C spec, and the spec of the device connector if it is not USB-C.

Please don't try soldering USB cables, you are far more likely to damage expensive hardware than save $20 on the right part.